# PHP ООП, статические функции

Tags: php, ооп

Вопрос. Как из статической функции обратиться к нестатической функции того же класса. Никак не могу нагуглить. Спасибо.

Comment: _"слышал звон, не знаю где он"_

Answer (score -1):

Чтоб обратиться к нестатическому методу класса, надо сначала создать экземпляр этого класса.

```
class Car {
  public function getColor() {}
  public static function getDefaultColor() {
    return (new self())->getColor();
  }
}
```

Comment: вот это бред вы написали

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: вопрос лучше минусуйте чем ответ.

Comment: Побежимов Борис, поясните. Доступ к методам класса осуществляется только через инстанс самого класса? Или может быть что-то внезапно поменялось? Из статического метода вы не имете доступа к $this, потому что его нету. Объект не создан. Поэтому, чтоб вызвать какой либо не статический метод, надо создать экземпляр класса new ClassName().

Comment: @Profesor08 ну бред как минимум потому что методы класса не вызываются через точку в php

Comment: Давай как максимум.